# chrome flags how to enable "allow-insecure-localhost" via command

Tags: google-chrome

found command to enable but did not work as expected

"open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-insecure-localhost"

able to enable that on UI and relaunch the chrome will work but not using command as below

"open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-insecure-localhost"

any help please?